# Creating Docker Image from Dockerfile

Tags: powershell, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I need to create a docker image with a Dockerfile which is available on a remote computer.

will the below work in Powershell ?

docker build -t MyFirstDockerImage -f //RemoteServerpath/FolderStructure/ .

Comment: Did you try your proposed solution? Did it work? That should answer your question.

Comment: I don't have a remote server to try on.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker build` can only read local files. But not the remote files. i.e Files should be copied on to the machine where docker build is being executed.